# MySQL Query - return value for past 12 months record for each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get past 12 months booking date count, but for the months with no booking, i need to get Null or 0. My query below skips the months with no booking,

```
SELECT bs.date,CONCAT(MONTHNAME(bs.date),' ', YEAR(bs.date)) as 'Month',count(*) AS Bookings, CONCAT(us.firstName,' ', us.lastName) as 'Name' from bookings bs RIGHT JOIN users us ON bs.clientID = us.recNo
        WHERE bs.managerID = 6 AND bs.clientID = 1900
        AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND date <= CURDATE() GROUP BY YEAR(date), month(date)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by hardcoding the 12 months in there and CROSS JOIN with `users` then LEFT JOIN with `bookings` (I have heard others mentioned that LEFT JOIN is way faster than RIGHT JOIN).
So query below

```
SELECT bs.date,
      CONCAT(MONTHNAME(hardcoded.date),' ', YEAR(hardcoded.date)) as 'Month',
       count(bs.date) AS Bookings,
      CONCAT(us.firstName,' ', us.lastName) as 'Name' 
from 
(SELECT CURDATE() as date UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 2 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 4 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 6 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 8 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 10 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 11 MONTH
 )as hardcoded
CROSS JOIN users us
LEFT JOIN bookings bs ON (MONTH(bs.date) = MONTH(hardcoded.date)
                       AND YEAR(bs.date) = YEAR(hardcoded.date))
                      AND bs.clientID = us.recNo
WHERE ((bs.managerID = 6 AND bs.clientID = 1900)
        OR
      (bs.managerID IS NULL AND bs.clientID IS NULL))
AND hardcoded.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND hardcoded.date <= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY Month,Name
ORDER BY hardcoded.date
```

see this in ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98c5a/12/0))
Note: because have a WHERE condition to check on managerID and clientID to filter out results we want but we also want to return rows that have nulls meaning it's our hardcoded months that have no bookings. that's why there's the `OR (bs.managerID IS NULL AND bs.clientID IS NULL)`
Also the current GROUP BY is NON-Standard as it is not grouping the first field of the select `bs.date` so right now if you have 2 or more bookings in one month, it just returns a date not knowing which one which seems odd, you might want to select `hardcoded.date` instead and GROUP BY that too so that you have a ANSI-Standard proper GROUP BY. Or better yet use an aggregate function like MIN() or MAX() to MIN(bs.date) or MAX(bs.date) for the first field in the select to make sure it always returns the first booking date or the last booking date for a each month if that month has 2 or more bookings, so that you don't don't list it in the GROUP BY.

I don't know if the CROSS JOIN is killing your app or not but you can try this one
it's without the CROSS JOIN but preserving your RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT bs.date,
 CONCAT(MONTHNAME(hardcoded.date),' ', YEAR(hardcoded.date)) as 'Month',
 count(bs.date) AS Bookings,
 CONCAT(us.firstName,' ', us.lastName) as 'Name' 
from 
(SELECT CURDATE() as date UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 2 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 4 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 6 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 8 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 10 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 11 MONTH
 )as hardcoded
LEFT JOIN bookings bs ON (MONTH(bs.date) = MONTH(hardcoded.date)
 AND YEAR(bs.date) = YEAR(hardcoded.date))
RIGHT JOIN users us ON (bs.clientID = us.recNo OR bs.clientID IS NULL)
WHERE ((bs.managerID = 6 AND bs.clientID = 1900)
 OR
 (bs.managerID IS NULL AND bs.clientID IS NULL))
AND hardcoded.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND hardcoded.date <= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY Month,Name
ORDER BY hardcoded.date
```

Trying to narrow down records before JOINING

```
SELECT MIN(bs.date) as FirstBookingDate,
 CONCAT(MONTHNAME(hardcoded.date),' ', YEAR(hardcoded.date)) as 'Month',
 count(bs.date) AS Bookings,
 CONCAT(us.firstName,' ', us.lastName) as 'Name' 
from 
(SELECT CURDATE() as date UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 2 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 4 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 6 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 8 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 10 MONTH UNION
 SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 11 MONTH
 )as hardcoded
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE recNo = 1900) us
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE managerID = 6 AND clientID = 1900
           AND date BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 11 MONTH AND CURDATE()) bs 
 ON (MONTH(bs.date) = MONTH(hardcoded.date)
 AND YEAR(bs.date) = YEAR(hardcoded.date))
GROUP BY Month,Name
ORDER BY hardcoded.date
```

Comment: It works well in Fiddle, but the query is not returning anything in phpmyadmin, infact it gets struck until i manually kill the application. Any idea?

Comment: How large is your users table?

Comment: Not sure if the CROSS JOIN is killing you or not depending on how large your users table is. but I just updated my answer with another query on bottom without the CROSS JOIN (but preserves your RIGHT JOIN)

Comment: This query doesn't give me all the month, i don't have any booking for May and results skips May. I wonder how it works in Fiddle and not in my code.

Comment: Do you mean the size of the table, Users - 1MiB with 4,492 rows and Bookings - 7.3MiB with some 98,000 rows

Comment: i just updated my answer with a 3rd version of the query, that tries to narrow down records before JOINING see if that one runs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with MySQL syntax, but I would approach this by first creating a temp table with only month and year integer columns and inserting a record for each month of the past year. A simple WHILE loop using DATESUB and a decrementing counter would probably suffice.
Then left join the temp table with your bookings/users query much as you have it now. This should result in months without bookings still showing in your output.
I don't believe you can pull it off in only one SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-queries for that, as it is demonstrated in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddbce9/12):

```
select y, n, concat(monthname(makedate(y, n*29)), ' ', y) yearmonth FROM
(select n,y FROM 
 (select 1 as n from dual
Union All
select 2 as n from dual
Union All
select 3 as n from dual
Union All
select 4 as n from dual
Union All
select 5 as n from dual
Union All
select 6 as n from dual
Union All
select 7 as n from dual
Union All
select 8 as n from dual
Union All
select 9 as n from dual
Union All
select 10 as n from dual
Union All
select 11 as n from dual
Union All
select 12 as n from dual) as months
inner join (select distinct year(dt) y from test) as years on 1=1) AS ym
left join test on month(dt) = n and year(dt) = y
group by n, y order by y, n
```

Applying the above query to your statement:

```
select y, n, concat(monthname(makedate(y, n*29)), ' ', y) yearmonth FROM
(select n,y FROM 
 (select 1 as n from dual
Union All
select 2 as n from dual
Union All
select 3 as n from dual
Union All
select 4 as n from dual
Union All
select 5 as n from dual
Union All
select 6 as n from dual
Union All
select 7 as n from dual
Union All
select 8 as n from dual
Union All
select 9 as n from dual
Union All
select 10 as n from dual
Union All
select 11 as n from dual
Union All
select 12 as n from dual) as months
inner join (select distinct year(dt) y 
from bookings 
where date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND date <= CURDATE()) as years on 1=1) AS ym
left join (
SELECT MONTH(bs.date) AS mth, YEAR(bs.date) as yr, count(*) AS Bookings, 
CONCAT(us.firstName,' ', us.lastName) as 'Name' 
from bookings bs RIGHT JOIN users us ON bs.clientID = us.recNo
WHERE bs.managerID = 6 AND bs.clientID = 1900
AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND date <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY MONTH(bs.date), YEAR(bs.date)) as test on mth = n and yr = y
group by n, y order by y, n
```