# MySQL Query - Return data for past 4 months and if no data for a particular month return 0

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My question is similar to this question: [MySQL Query - return value for past 12 months record for each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081741/mysql-query-return-value-for-past-12-months-record-for-each-month)

But I can't work out how to implement it with my query.

I require the data for the previous 4 months and if there is none to output 0 for that month.

Here is my current queries in my codeigniter model:

```
function getMonthlySumOrders()
{
    $this->db->select("SUM(price_each*quantity) AS sum_monthly_price, DATE_FORMAT(job.order_date, '%M') AS 'order_date', customer.company_name", false);
    $this->db->join('job', 'job.job_id = job_details.job_id');
    $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.company_id = job.company_id');
    $this->db->where('job.company_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->where('month(job.order_date)<=', date("m"));
    $this->db->where('month(job.order_date)>=', date("m")-3);
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(job.order_date)');
    $this->db->order_by('job.order_date', "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get('job_details');

return $query->result_array();
}

function getMonthlySumCompleted()
{
    $this->db->select("SUM(price_each*quantity) AS sum_monthly_price", false);
    $this->db->join('job', 'job.job_id = job_details.job_id');
    $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.company_id = job.company_id');
    $this->db->where('job.company_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->where('month(job.completed_date)<=', date("m"));
    $this->db->where('month(job.completed_date)>=', date("m")-3);
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(job.completed_date)');
    $this->db->order_by('job.completed_date', "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get('job_details');

return $query->result_array();
}
```

At the moment the query is returning results for the correct date period but doesn't show 0 when there are no values, and so the order between both sets of data goes out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($query-num_rows() > 0)
{
return $query->result_array();
}
else
{
return "0";
}
```